# Spring producing 404 for valid URL

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building a simple Spring application with the goal of returning "Hello world" as a foundation to build upon. I set up a clean project last night following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) guide which worked and now I'm trying to bring an already existing project to the same functionality.

I have two files called `ApplicationConfig.java` and `Controller.java` tasked with returning a string when a certain URL is hit. When I visit `localhost:8080` it renders my `index.html` with a link to the URL I wish to return a string at. When I visit the URL `localhost:8080/home/greet` it returns a 404.

My `ApplicationConfig.java`:

```
package application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run   (ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }

}
```

and my `Controller.java`

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    public String greeting() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

As far as I see `/home/greet/` should produce a page that just reads "Hello" but this isn't the case. What is the issue?

Here is my `pom.xml` and what my project structure looks like, should they be relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

[image: structure]

Comment: Where is your ViewResolver??

Comment: @PrasannaKumar The tutorial which worked last night did not make use of a ViewResolver.

Comment: @Jens These suggestions did not work, thank you though.

Comment: Without ViewResolver how can it redirect to page??

Comment: I haven't set that up yet, I'm simply trying to return a string at this point.

Comment: @PrasannaKumar look at the `class` level annotation `@RestController`. the methods inside the class will by default get the `@ResponseBody `annotation, hence no need of a `ViewResolver.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entrypoint class `ApplicationConfig.java` is in `application` package and `Controller.java` is in `controller` package.

SpringBoot scans for Spring components in the package( and sub-packages) where EntryPoint class is.

So move your controller to `application` or any nested package under `application`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Add your **ApplicationConfig.java** in `package abc.app;`

Step 2 : Add your **Controller.java** in `package abc.app.controller;`.

Step 3 : add `@ComponentScan("abc.app")`  in **ApplicationConfig.java**.

For Example :

**ApplicationConfig.java:**

```
package abc.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("abc.app")
public class ApplicationConfig {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run   (ApplicationConfig.class, args);
  }

}
```

**Controller.java :**

```
package abc.app.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping("/greet")
public String greeting() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

I Hope you Find your Right Solution here.